# how to add float in animation as I slide down in parallax website

Tags: wordpress, css

i want to know how to add effects as like in my website created using wix [anjeneyagroups(wix)](https://letterpop0.wixsite.com/website-2)

Currently I am creating website using wordpress , so I need some experts to suggest me a plugin or css to add effects to each element as I scroll down my website. my current website is [anjneyagroups(wordpress)](http://anjeneyagroups.in)

Answer (score 0):

Waypoints is a good library to use if you need to trigger animations at specific points on the page.

http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/

You can then use something like Transit to run your animations once a waypoint is triggered.

http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/